# Does guava have an equivalent to Python's reduce function?

Tags: java, guava, functional-programming

Does guava (or another java library) have something like reduce() function in Python?

I'm looking for something like this http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reduce

Comment: Java SE 8 will probably add `Collections.reduce` once lambdas are added. FWIW Python 3 encourages an explicit for-loop instead of reduce; reduce was moved from the built-ins to the [functools](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html) module.

Comment: @ide: It may well even have a `Collection.reduce` method, given that there will be extension methods. I know they plan to add stuff like `filter` and `map` as extension methods.

Comment: Does http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/ ? Not sure so just a comment...

Comment: Have a look at http://functionaljava.org

Comment: [<B> B fj.data.List#foldLeft(F<B, F<A, B>> f, B b)](https://github.com/functionaljava/functionaljava/blob/master/core/src/main/java/fj/data/List.java#L652)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've not (yet) managed to find any Java collections libraries that support `map` and `reduce`.  (I exclude map/reduce functionality in parallel / distributed processing frameworks ... because you need a "big" problem for these frameworks to be worthwhile.)

Probably, the reason for this "lack" is that map/reduce coding without closures is just too cumbersome.  Too much boilerplate code, too much heavy-weight syntax.  Since the main point of using map / reduce primitives on simple collections is to make your code simple and elegant ...

---

@CurtainDog contributed a link to [lambdaj](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/).  That does the kind of thing that the OP is after (though there's no method specifically called `reduce`).  But it illustrates what I was saying about boilerplate.  Notice that many of the higher order operations involve creating classes that extend one or other of the `Closure` classes.

(FWIW, I think that the [`Lambda.aggregate(...)`](http://lambdaj.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html/apidocs/index.html) methods are the lambdaj analog of `reduce`.)

Comment: @user359996 - You've just linked to the root of the Guava javadoc tree.  What's the point of that?

Comment: Believe it or not, that wasn't on purpose. Here is the correct link: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#transform(java.util.List,%20com.google.common.base.Function)

Answer (score 7):

No. It might eventually, though functional stuff like that isn't a core focus of Guava. See [this issue](https://github.com/google/guava/issues/218).

Answer (score 5):

Java 8 streams allow you to do this.

```
mylist.stream().map((x) -> x + 1).reduce((a,b) -> a + b)
```

For more information: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html

Answer (score 4):

I have recently [submitted an issue](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=546) where I requested / discussed something similar. This is what would be needed in my implementation

```
/**
 * Aggregate the selected values from the supplied {@link Iterable} using
 * the provided selector and aggregator functions.
 * 
 * @param <I>
 *            the element type over which to iterate
 * @param <S>
 *            type of the values to be aggregated
 * @param <A>
 *            type of the aggregated value
 * @param data
 *            elements for aggregation
 * @param selectorFunction
 *            a selector function that extracts the values to be aggregated
 *            from the elements
 * @param aggregatorFunction
 *            function that performs the aggregation on the selected values
 * @return the aggregated value
 */
public static <I, S, A> A aggregate(final Iterable<I> data,
    final Function<I, S> selectorFunction,
    final Function<Iterable<S>, A> aggregatorFunction){
    checkNotNull(aggregatorFunction);
    return aggregatorFunction.apply(
        Iterables.transform(data, selectorFunction)
    );
}
```

(The selector function can pull the value to aggregate from the object to query, but in many cases it will be `Functions.identity()`, i.e. the object itself is what's aggregated)

This is not a classic fold, but it requires a `Function<Iterable<X>,X>` to do the work. But since the actual code is a one-liner, I have instead chosen to request some standard aggregator functions (I'd put them in a class called something like `Aggregators`, `AggregatorFunctions` or even `Functions.Aggregators`):

```
/** A Function that returns the average length of the Strings in an Iterable. */
public static Function<Iterable<String>,Integer> averageLength()

/** A Function that returns a BigDecimal that corresponds to the average
    of all numeric values passed from the iterable. */
public static Function<Iterable<? extends Number>,BigDecimal> averageOfFloats()

/** A Function that returns a BigInteger that corresponds to the average
    of all numeric values passed from the iterable. */
public static Function<Iterable<? extends Number>,BigInteger> averageOfIntegers()

/** A Function that returns the length of the longest String in an Iterable. */    
public static Function<Iterable<String>,Integer> maxLength()

/** A Function that returns the length of the shortest String in an Iterable. */
public static Function<Iterable<String>,Integer> minLength()

/** A Function that returns a BigDecimal that corresponds to the sum of all
    numeric values passed from the iterable. */
public static Function<Iterable<? extends Number>,BigDecimal> sumOfFloats()

/** A Function that returns a BigInteger that corresponds to the integer sum
    of all numeric values passed from the iterable. */
public static Function<Iterable<? extends Number>,BigInteger> sumOfIntegers()
```

(You can see my sample implementations in the issue)

That way, you can do things like this:

```
int[] numbers = { 1, 5, 6, 9, 11111, 54764576, 425623 };
int sum = Aggregators.sumOfIntegers().apply(Ints.asList(numbers)).intValue();
```

This is definitely not what you are asking for, but it would make like easier in many cases and would overlap with your request (even if the approach is different).

Answer (score 4):

Jedi has a [reduce](http://jedi.codehaus.org/javadoc/jedi/functional/FunctionalPrimitives.html#reduce%28java.lang.Iterable,%20jedi.functional.Functor2%29) operation. Jedi also helps reduce the boiler plate by using annotations to generate functors for you. See these [examples](http://jedi.codehaus.org/Examples).

Answer (score 4):

Guava has [transform](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#transform-java.lang.Iterable-com.google.common.base.Function-) (map). Seems like reduce is missing though?

Answer (score 1):

I have developed a library to do map/filter/reduce with standard J2SE.
Sorry it is in french, but with google translate you can read it :
http://caron-yann.developpez.com/tutoriels/java/fonction-object-design-pattern-attendant-closures-java-8/

You can use if like this :

```
int sum = dogs.filter(new Predicate<Arguments2<Dog, Integer>>() {

    @Override
    public Boolean invoke(Arguments2<Dog, Integer> arguments) {
        // filter on male
        return arguments.getArgument1().getGender() == Dog.Gender.MALE;
    }
}).<Integer>map(new Function<Integer, Arguments2<Dog, Integer>>() {

    @Override
    public Integer invoke(Arguments2<Dog, Integer> arguments) {
        // get ages
        return arguments.getArgument1().getAge();
    }
}).reduce(new Function<Integer, Arguments2<Integer, Integer>>() {

    @Override
    public Integer invoke(Arguments2<Integer, Integer> arguments) {
        // sum âges
        return arguments.getArgument1() + arguments.getArgument2();
    }
});

System.out.println("Le cumul de l'âge des mâles est de : " + sum + " ans");
```

Enjoy this help

Answer (score 0):

Use [Totally Lazy](http://code.google.com/p/totallylazy/), it implements all of those things an even more. 
It basicly copied the whole funcional approach from [Clojure](http://clojure.org/).